# Specflow : generate tests with underscore between words

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, specflow

In specflow, if you create a scenario with a name such as "Do something usefull", the generated unit test will be named "DoSomethingUsefull" (without spaces). This is not very readeable in the nunit test runner if you have long names for scenarios.

Is there a way to separate words with underscore? (like a setting?)

Answer (score 3):

The only way now is to modify the SpecFlow's source code

```
namespace TechTalk.SpecFlow
{
    public static string ToIdentifierPart(this string text)
    {
        text = firstWordCharRe.Replace(text, match => match.Groups["pre"].Value + match.Groups["fc"].Value.ToUpper());

        // --- add this line ---
        text = text.Replace(" ", "_");   

        text = punctCharRe.Replace(text, "_");
        text = RemoveAccentChars(text);

        if (text.Length > 0)
            text = text.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + text.Substring(1);

        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: True - but in OSS spirit; head to https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow and create an issue for this. I think this would be great - especially with a setting to switch it